# Large difference in contingency table level affecting Cramer's V?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, categorical-data, association-measure, cramers-v

The Wikipedia article for [Cramer's V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V) states the following without citation:

> Note that as chi-squared values tend to increase with the number of
>   cells, the greater the difference between r (rows) and c (columns),
>   the more likely $φ_c$ will tend to 1 without strong evidence of a
>   meaningful correlation.

I'm empirically seeing evidence of that in a dataset I'm analyzing, but since this statement is without citation (and I don't have the statistical chops to explore its veracity myself), I'm not sure if I can accept that as a theoretical explanation for what I'm observing. Might the community be able to shed some light on this?

Comment: I wonder what "meaningful" correlation means...